# I'm trying to set up a form's success state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm reworking my professional portfolio (recent bootcamp grad) and I'm having issues with setting up the contact submit forms success message. I've been looking everywhere the past few days, and can't seem to find a good direction with it. I was hoping someone on here could give me that direction, or just flat out tell me what I'm doing wrong.

- Thanks

setting up formSuccess in state (init value false), and changing it to true on submit. Google searched for other solutions, videos on other solutions but there isn't a lot out there on the matter.

```
class FormWrapper extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      comments: "",
      formSuccess: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Form ["success" prop goes here as "success"]>
          <Message
            success
            header="E-mail has been sent"
            content="Please give me a few business to reply!"
          />
          <Button color="teal">
            {" "}
            <Icon.Group size="large">
              <Icon name="paper plane" />
            </Icon.Group>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

- not the full file

Answer (score 0):

Hey welcome to the wild world of web dev and congrats on finishing your bootcamp.

Your approach seems pretty much like the correct way to do it but you're not actually using your `handleSubmit` so nothing is ever going to happen. I'm not sure if you've just omitted it. You mentioned you're not showing all your code so maybe something is missing. You should attach the following to your `<Form />`

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    formSuccess: true,
  });
}

...

<Form
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
  success={this.state.formSuccess}
>

// rest of your code/component
```

You can check it out working in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/5mw875or0p?fontsize=14&module=%2Fexample.js) in `example.js`.

Going forward, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about asking questions on StackOverflow so people can help you out faster and more easily. The easier your problem is to understand, the better help you'll get.

Comment: haha yeah I totally just omitted the handleSubmit, and handleChange functions. I'll be sure to checkout the article you sent me as well as the working example. Thank you for the direction. Web development certainly is a beast!

Comment: Hey Jared, Where did you find that example of working code from? I'm trying to implement the missing form state, but the documents do not show a good example of implementation. Thanks -Sal

Comment: @SalvatoreArgentieri The code is used is the example provided in the docs https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#states-success If you click the link for CodeSandbox, you may be able to see it more clearly

Comment: alright got ya bro. Even the sandbox seems to be weird for me so I must be doing something wrong. I did figure it out however. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
class FormWrapper extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      comments: "",
      formSuccess: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  _formSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault
    this.setState({formSuccess:true});
    //call other methods or api after this or in setState callback
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Form onSubmit={this._formSubmit}>
          <Message
            success
            header="E-mail has been sent"
            content="Please give me a few business to reply!"
          />
          <Button  color="teal">
            {" "}
            <Icon.Group size="large">
              <Icon name="paper plane" />
            </Icon.Group>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

Try with this code and also make sure your button is of type submit from semantic-ui-react.

Comment: Krina, thanks for the assist! I needed to combine what Jared, and you recommended to get the successful form to work! Y'all are great!

Comment: Okay. Great !!
Thanks. Happy Coding